# Image processing to recognize digits

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

I have scanned documents where I have extracted the page numbers. They are grainy and I would like to see if fixing this graininess could help a ML neural net recognize the digits better.

I am having trouble finding what I am looking for. This is not quite image smoothing. I tried blurring, and [a simple filter convolution from this tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#). 
But it is not doing quite what I would like.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: Blurry 2]

[image: Blurry 36]

[image: Blurry 5]

Comment: If that is the quality of your scanning, I would have to recommend you re-scan.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that a closing or dilation operation could somewhat improve your results, at least if the contours of your digits are not completely corrupted.

I'd recommend you to look into [OpenCVs Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html), especially part 2 (Dilation) and 4 (Closing).